# Placing values of JSON array into PHP variables

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to get array items from JSON to save in a mysql database. When recieved from android, it is in the form:

```
array(1) {
["records"]=>
string(215) "[{"total":"12.0","product":"Sample1","id":"0","qty":"2","invoice":"2.5082015071735E13"},{"total":"15870.0","product":"Sample2","id":"0","qty":"23","invoice":"2.5082015071735E13"}]"
```

PHP CODE:

```
if($_POST)
{
echo "Smething was sent";

$JSON_Entry = $_POST["Entry"];


$obj = json_decode($JSON_Entry,true);



foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $index => $item)
    {
        echo $index;
    }
}

}
}
```

I have only gone as far as a foreach statement:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

which displays:

```
[{"total":"12.0","product":"Uganda Waragi 200ml 24x01","id":"0","qty":"2","invoice":"2.5082015071735E13"},{"total":"15870.0","product":"Gilbeys Gin 35cl 24x01 EL","id":"0","qty":"23","invoice":"2.5082015071735E13"}]
```

trying to implement a nested foreach displays an invalid argument supplied error. Is there a way i can effectively get the different values to save in variables or is there an issue with my syntax?

UPDATE::
print_r($obj) outputs:

```
Array
(
   [records] => [ {"total":"12.0",
                   "product":"Uganda Waragi 200ml 24x01",
                   "id":"0",
                   "qty":"2",
                   "invoice":"2.5082015071735E13"}, 

                  {"total":"15870.0",
                   "product":"Gilbeys Gin 35cl 24x01 EL",
                   "id":"0",
                   "qty":"23",
                   "invoice":"2.5082015071735E13"}
                 ]
)
```

*UPDATE 2*

```
echo $_POST["Entry"];  outputs : 

{"records":"[{\"total\":\"12.0\",\"product\":\"Sample1\",\"id\":\"0\",\"qty\":\‌​"2\",\"invoice\":\"2.5082015071735E13\"},{\"total\":\"15870.0\",\"product\":\"Sam‌​ple2\",\"id\":\"0\",\"qty\":\"23\",\"invoice\":\"2.5082015071735E13\"}]"}
```

UPDATE 3:
JAVA CODE:

```
ArrayList<RecieptHeader> invoiceList = db.getInvoiceHeader();
        ArrayList<SalesReciepts> entryList = db.getSalesRecords();

        ArrayList<String> contact = new ArrayList<String>();


        List<NameValuePair> postVars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        JSONObject JSONheader = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray recordsJsonArray = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < entryList.size(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject JSONentry = new JSONObject(); // here you create a new JSONObject

                JSONentry.put("id", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getEntryId()));
                JSONentry.put("invoice",String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getInvoice_id()));
                JSONentry.put("product", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getProduct()));
                JSONentry.put("qty", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getQty()));
                JSONentry.put("total", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getTotal()));

                recordsJsonArray.put(JSONentry); // here you add the item to your array
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        JSONObject sent = new JSONObject();

        try {

                sent.put("records", String.valueOf(recordsJsonArray));
        }
        catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





        try {
            JSONheader.put("Invoice", String.valueOf(invoiceList));
        }
        catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






        postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Entry", String.valueOf(sent)));
        postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Header", String.valueOf(JSONheader)));

        //Declare and Initialize Http Clients and Http Postsz
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(POST_PRODUCTS);

        //Format it to be sent
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postVars));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Send request and Get the Response Back */
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


            Log.e("response:", responseBody );

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.v("MAD", "Error sending... ");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.v("MAD", "Error sending... ");


        }



        return result;
```

Comment: did you do a `json_decode` before your foreach loop ?

Comment: yes. adding full php code

Comment: Can you do a `print_r()` before your foreach loop on `$obj`, see if that is being converted to array

Comment: RE: @Criesto request. Edit your question with the results of the `print_r()` so we can see it.

Comment: For some reason the `json_decode()` does not seem to have decoded the whole JSON String? Can you also add the results of `echo $_POST["Entry"];` to your question

Comment: @Criesto This is impossible to answer until the OP gives us some more accurate insite to what the raw JSON String looks like.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  .. `echo $_POST["Entry"];`outputs : `{"records":"[{\"total\":\"12.0\",\"product\":\"Sample1\",\"id\":\"0\",\"qty\":\"2\",\"invoice\":\"2.5082015071735E13\"},{\"total\":\"15870.0\",\"product\":\"Sample2\",\"id\":\"0\",\"qty\":\"23\",\"invoice\":\"2.5082015071735E13\"}]"}`

Comment: That JSON String is **not valid JSON**, paste it into http://jsonlint.org/ and see the errors

Comment: @RiggsFolly .... think it has to do with when I was placing the JSON Array in the JSON Object. Updating the main code

Comment: The best way to create json data is to think about how you want to process it whereever it is going. So create an object that contains a property called `invoices` of type `array` add `n` invoice entries to that array. Then its easy to build and easy to process by the receiver

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    var_dump(json_decode($value));
}
```

i think json string should start with {} brackets, not []

Comment: JSON Strings that start with `[` and end with `]` are JSON String representations of ARRAYS

Comment: @RiggsFolly .... what about the curly brackets? there are two sets of information, each within a set of curly brackets. can they also be considered an array? I think thats the source of m problem

Comment: Curly brackets denote an Object. However PHP allows you to convert Objects into arrays `json_decode($string,TRUE)` for those who are afraid of objects. Oh and of course you can have objects in arays and arrays in objects

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's **json_decode()** function, this will convert a JSON string into an array.